# Can't set CSS rules with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

This is my HTML

```
<div id="myButton" class="selfDistrucitonButton">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="height">
       <div class="inner"> Button </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS

```
document.getElementsByName('myButton').style.marginLeft = "90px";
document.getElementsByName('myButton').style.marginTop = "40px";
document.getElementsByName('myButton').style.width = "400px";
```

It generate an error on the console: "Cannot set property of undefined".

Even `console.log("document.getElementById("myButton");` it say to me that the button is NULL. I really don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `document.getElementById` not `name`,

```
document.getElementById('myButton').style.marginLeft = "90px";
```

Since your `div` is having an `id` attribute with value `myButton`. Not name.

And the full code would be,

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myButton');
elem.style.marginLeft = "90px";
elem.style.marginTop = "40px";
elem.style.width = "400px";
```

Comment: @Giulio Where did you put your script tag?

Comment: @Giulio There is the problem. Put your script tag as a last immediate child of your body. Like, `<body>....other html...<script></script></body>`

Comment: @Rob Why? There is no reason for doing so. `40 + "px"` is equal to `"40px"`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It works!, please, can you explain me why i have to do like this?

Comment: @Giulio when your js code executes in the head tag, the element that you are searching in the document will not be available. html will render elements from top to bottom. So it searches for element with that id, and null will be returned as there is no such elements in the document at that point of time.